# Cannot alias database connection string in conf/neo4j.conf when using apoc.load.jdbc()

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j installed using docker-compose and successfully enabled apoc plug-in.

I'm able to use call
`apoc.load.jdbc("hard-coded-db-connection-string", "my-table")`
to retrieve data from my database which is good.

Of course, this is not convenient, so I tried to alias the connection string by adding below to the conf/neo4j.conf.
`apoc.jdbc.mydb.url=jdbc:postgresql://"hard-coded-db-connection-string`
and then restarted the container. However i can't call the apoc using the alias and I see a message in the log:

> Unrecognized setting. No declared setting with name: apoc.jdbc.mydb.url

I also tried to run below to check the settings in the conf/neo4j.conf file, but the results don't show the alias line i just added.

```
CALL dbms.listConfig()
YIELD name, value
WHERE name STARTS WITH 'apoc.'
RETURN name, value
ORDER BY name
;
```

Wondering can someone help me troubleshooting this? Is this because I was working on the wrong conf file? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use an apoc.conf file instead.

Since 4.x neo4j got more restrictive with variable  settings In neo4j.conf

Comment: hi Michael, thanks for your advice. Should I just create the apoc.conf file, add the db connection string and put it under the $home/conf folder?